# Why does refractive index increase with concentration of the medium?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, speed-of-light, refraction, density

I learnt that lights decrease velocity in a medium during absorbance and emission of its energy in the charged particles in the medium. From the Beer's law, I read that absorbance is directly proportional to the concentration of the medium.

Can this be an explanation for the reason why refractive index increase with concentration? If not, what would be an appropriate explanation for it?

Comment: This paper answers your question: Beyond Beer's Law: Why the Index of Refraction Depends (Almost) Linearly ... https://chemistry-europe.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/cphc.202000018